# HTML button to revbeal password input field

Tags: linux, bash, perl, passwords

I have a table with 7 columns. One of them contains passwords (pw).

I dont want to show the passwords on my website: I would like to have some kind of "click to expand" in the table to show it.

Here is a part of the script that contains the table:

```
...

push @certlist, {
    state     => $cert[0],
    'expire'  => $date,
    'subject' => $cert[5],
    'cn'      => $cn,
    'ip'      => $ccd_ips->{$cn},
    'dl'      => '',
    're'      => '',
    'pw'      => $password->{$cn}
};
```

...

```
return $q->table(
    { 'class' => 'certs' },
    $q->Tr(
        [
            $q->th(
                [   'Status', 'Common Name', 'D',         'Password',
                    'Date',   'Subject',     'IP-Adress', 'R'
                ]
            ) . "\n",
            map {
                  $q->td( { 'class' => $_->{'state'} }, $states{ $_->{'state'} } ) .
                  $q->td( [ @$_{qw(cn dl pw expire subject ip re)} ] ) . "\n"
            } @certlist
        ]
    )
) . "\n";

...
```

Comment: You will need to include the passwords in some way. What's the reason you want them masked? Think about that first. Do you care if they are there as clear text in the source of the website, so that you'd just not see them at a glance and the user needs to make some effort to get one? Or is this a security concern?

Comment: It has a security reason

Comment: Huh. That's tricky. Do you serve that page through SSL/https? Are you afraid that someone might listen in? Please be _very specific_. I'm trying to narrow down what you want to do exactly. Right now your question is too broad. It's more about process than about programming. That code looks scary, too. I can explain what it does, but that won't help. So your code is not the issue yet as it seems you don't really know what to do yet. (And probably also not _how_ to do that, but that's the point. That does not matter at this point).

Comment: So all I want to know if it is somehow possible to create something like an onclick sub, where I have something like a button where a passwords is standing. And onclick it should show the password.

Comment: This is a good example of why the HTML generation functions in CGI.pm ought never to be used. While the wisdom of storing and transmitting plain text passwords is another topic, the idea that one should have to manipulate Perl code to add some JavaScript to a page is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You should only add a class, say `password-container` to elements that contain passwords. Set the initial content to masked.

That is:

```
push @certlist, {
    state     => $cert[0],
    'expire'  => $date,
    'subject' => $cert[5],
    'cn'      => $cn,
    'ip'      => $ccd_ips->{$cn},
    'dl'      => '',
    're'      => '',
    'pw'      => '*' x 8,
};
```

Add a bit of JavaScript to the page to add an `onclick` handler for all elements with the `password-container` class which handles the toggling.

```
return $q->table(
    { 'class' => 'certs' },
    $q->Tr(
        [
            $q->th(
                [   'Status', 'Common Name', 'D',         'Password',
                    'Date',   'Subject',     'IP-Adress', 'R'
                ]
            ) . "\n",
            map {
                  $q->td( { 'class' => $_->{'state'} }, $states{ $_->{'state'} } ) .
                  $q->td( [ @$_{qw(cn dl)} ]) .
                  $q->td( { 'class' => 'password_container' }, $_->{pw} ) .
                  $q->td( [ @$_{qw(expire subject ip re)} ] ) . "\n"
            } @certlist
        ]
    )
) . "\n";
```

or some similar garbage.

This, once again, shows the value of not generating HTML using CGI.pm. Instead use templates. That's just advice for the future, I am assuming you can't fix the existing codebase.

BTW, here is a relevant bit from [CGI.pm documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used):

> All HTML generation functions within `CGI.pm` are no longer being maintained. Any issues, bugs, or patches will be rejected unless they relate to fundamentally broken page rendering.
>
> The rationale for this is that the HTML generation functions of `CGI.pm` are an obfuscation at best and a maintenance nightmare at worst. You should be using a template engine for better separation of concerns. See `CGI::Alternatives` for an example of using `CGI.pm` with the `Template::Toolkit` module.
>
> These functions, and perldoc for them, are considered deprecated, they are no longer being maintained and no fixes or features for them will be accepted. They will, however, continue to exist in CGI.pm without any deprecation warnings ("soft" deprecation) so you can continue to use them if you really want to. All documentation for these functions has been moved to `CGI::HTML::Functions`.

Comment: Presumably you're intedning that the JavaScript will change the input type from `password` to `text`?

Comment: I am agnostic on the details. If I were doing this from scratch, I would not send the password in the first place, only asterisks or some such masking character. Then clicking would transfer the password for that particular certificate and only that one. I am assuming this is some kind of in-house certificate management system. Even then the passwords should not be stored and displayed together with other info. But, this is not the place for that discussion.